# Sorting a three-dimensional php array by two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Here i am trying to sort(in descending) three dimensional array in php using values from another two dimensional array `[priority_used]`
Here `[10]` and `[5]` are campaign and there respective priorities are in `[priority_used]` with `[10] => 0.042857142857142` and `[5] => 0.95714285714286`

I have success in looping not in sorting - what I've tried so far:

```
<?php
foreach ($aDs as $id => $partie) {
    $priority = $id;
    echo $priority;
    foreach ($partie as $pid => $value) {
        $ad_id = $value['ad_id'];
        echo($ad_id);
    }
}



Array
(
    [ads] => Array
        (
            [10] => Array
                (
                    [736] => Array
                        (
                            [ad_id] => 736
                            [placement_id] => 140
                            [status] => 0
                            [width] => 300
                            [ext_bannertype] => bannerTypeHtml:oxHtml:genericHtml
                            [height] => 250
                            [type] => html
                            [contenttype] => 
                            [weight] => 1
                            [adserver] => 
                            [block_ad] => 0
                            [cap_ad] => 0
                            [session_cap_ad] => 0
                            [compiledlimitation] => 
                            [acl_plugins] => 
                            [alt_filename] => 
                            [priority] => 0.014285714285714
                            
                        )

                    [737] => Array
                        (
                            [ad_id] => 737
                            [placement_id] => 140
                            [status] => 0
                            [width] => 300
                            [ext_bannertype] => bannerTypeHtml:oxHtml:genericHtml
                            [height] => 250
                            [type] => html
                            [contenttype] => 
                            [weight] => 1
                            [adserver] => 
                            [block_ad] => 0
                            [cap_ad] => 0
                            [session_cap_ad] => 0
                            [compiledlimitation] => 
                            [acl_plugins] => 
                            [alt_filename] => 
                            [priority] => 0.014285714285714
                            
                        )

                    [738] => Array
                        (
                            [ad_id] => 738
                            [placement_id] => 140
                            [status] => 0
                            [width] => 300
                            [ext_bannertype] => bannerTypeHtml:oxHtml:genericHtml
                            [height] => 250
                            [type] => html
                            [contenttype] => 
                            [weight] => 1
                            [adserver] => 
                            [block_ad] => 0
                            [cap_ad] => 0
                            [session_cap_ad] => 0
                            [compiledlimitation] => 
                            [acl_plugins] => 
                            [alt_filename] => 
                            [priority] => 0.014285714285714
                           
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [742] => Array
                        (
                            [ad_id] => 742
                            [placement_id] => 142
                            [status] => 0
                            [width] => 300
                            [ext_bannertype] => bannerTypeHtml:oxHtml:genericHtml
                            [height] => 250
                            [type] => html
                            [contenttype] => 
                            [weight] => 1
                            [adserver] => 
                            [block_ad] => 0
                            [cap_ad] => 0
                            [session_cap_ad] => 0
                            [compiledlimitation] => 
                            [acl_plugins] => 
                            [alt_filename] => 
                            [priority] => 0.33333333333333
                            
                        )

                    [743] => Array
                        (
                            [ad_id] => 743
                            [placement_id] => 142
                            [status] => 0
                            [width] => 300
                            [ext_bannertype] => bannerTypeHtml:oxHtml:genericHtml
                            [height] => 250
                            [type] => html
                            [contenttype] => 
                            [weight] => 1
                            [adserver] => 
                            [block_ad] => 0
                            [cap_ad] => 0
                            [session_cap_ad] => 0
                            [compiledlimitation] => 
                            [acl_plugins] => 
                            [alt_filename] => 
                            [priority] => 0.33333333333333
                            
                        )

                    [744] => Array
                        (
                            [ad_id] => 744
                            [placement_id] => 142
                            [status] => 0
                            [width] => 300
                            [ext_bannertype] => bannerTypeHtml:oxHtml:genericHtml
                            [height] => 250
                            [type] => html
                            [contenttype] => 
                            [weight] => 1
                            [adserver] => 
                            [block_ad] => 0
                            [cap_ad] => 0
                            [session_cap_ad] => 0
                            [compiledlimitation] => 
                            [acl_plugins] => 
                            [alt_filename] => 
                            [priority] => 0.33333333333333
                           
                        )

                )

        )

    [priority_used] => Array
        (
            [ads] => Array
                (
                    [10] => 0.042857142857142
                    [5] => 0.95714285714286
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your expected output is.

Comment: i want to sort array [10] and [5] in dec.., according to  their [priority_used] value like for [10] => 0.042857142857142 and [5] => 0.95714285714286 so [5] have high value and should come first in [ads] array

Comment: I'm not sure what you've tried... show us your best attempt (code). Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the priority table needed sorting, but the main table needed rebuilding. That is because the sort from the priority table might look like `5,2,10,24`. So basically, we get the proper descending sort order from `$priority_used` using `arsort()`, then loop through the original data array and pluck out the sub-arrays that match, in order.

```
$order = $priority_used['ads'];
arsort($order);
$newdata= array( "ads" => [] );;
foreach($order as $key => $fraction) {
    $newdata['ads'][$key] = $data_array['ads'][$key];
}

print_r($newdata);
```

I have a working demo here:

https://www.tehplayground.com/woJbpi4b3ZB9YAQf

Comment: Array ([10] => Array ([736] => Array ([ad_id] => 736 ) [737] => Array ([ad_id] => 737 ) [738] => Array ([ad_id] => 738 ) ) [5] => Array ([742] => Array ([ad_id] => 742 ) [743] => Array ([ad_id] => 743 ) [744] => Array ([ad_id] => 744 ) ) )

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `$newdata[$key] = $data_array[$key];` ?

Comment: foreach($order as $key => $fraction) {
    $newdata[$key] = $data_array[$key];
}

print_r($newdata);

Comment: I might not understand what you mean then. If you like, paste in the modified array into your original question  and I'll take a look.

Comment: i said that if we remove the [ads] array than the code will look like $newdata= array(  ); foreach($order as $key => $fraction) { $newdata[$key] = $data_array[$key]; } print_r($newdata);

Comment: In your original question, you had 2 `$ads` arrays, the data array and the priority array. Which one of these is changing?